# for loop - execute file every 2 hr, output--> ssh "new server" execute output command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, ssh

the below script I gonna use for taking tape archive. each file will take 2hr time to archive.

in this case I need to keep sleep time as 2 hr to all file. and should ssh to server according to input and start executing output command to take archive. once 2 hr completed next file should take and start executing

/root/scripts/list (file)

```
/DATA/DataToTape/JAN_1991/
/DATA/DataToTape/JAN_1992/
/DATA/DataToTape/JAN_1993/
/DATA/DataToTape/JAN_1994/
/DATA/DataToTape/JAN_1995/
/DATA/DataToTape/JAN_1996/
/DATA/DataToTape/JAN_1997/
```

just i tried but couldn't helped --------------

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " pls enter sleep time:"
read sleep
echo "pls enter server to take archive"
read server
for i in $(cat /root/scripts/list)
path=$i
output=$(nohup dsmc arch $path -subdir=yes > /tsm/backuplogs/$(basename $path)_\`date +%d%m%y_%H_%M\`.log &) 
ssh "$server $output"
done
```

Comment: What is the problem that your script is having?

Comment: Why do you need to sleep? Why don't you let the dsmc command run in the foreground? Then the ssh command will only run after dsmc completes

Comment: I have only 7 drivers to archive.. at a time all the 7 drives take for each archive. in this case I am having 200 files to archive.  2 hrs once i need to execute archive command. is there any other way ?

Comment: @FuriousGeorge ./archive2.in: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `path='
./archive2.in: line 7: `path= $i'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need "do" after your "for" loop.  That will fix the problem in the comments above:

```
for i in $(cat /root/scripts/list); do
```